# C# How to get the value of a variable in another class using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm sure this is simple, but I'm struggling... all I want to do is read a string variable stored in another class, but using a string as the reference to point to that other class (it could be one of multiple classes, all of which have this variable included, this is why I have to use Reflection). Using Reflection I have been able to invoke a method in another class, so this does not seem so different... but so far I've had no luck getting this to work.  I'd appreciate any pointers (no pun intended!).

```cs
Class First
{
   public static string theStringToGet = "some text";
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Class Second
{
   String classRef = "Namespace.First";
   String localStr = ??? // I think something like: Type.GetType(classRef).GetField("theStringToGet").GetValue();

   // get value of 'theStringToGet' from 'First' class public var and store in 'localStr' in 'Second' class...
}
```

Comment: use public class first and you can resieve it with    First.theStringToGet

Comment: The class name will change so I need to be able to use a variable to define the class, so in effect "localStr = [classRef].theStringToGet"

Comment: At least please post valid code for the example

Comment: Why is the above not "valid" ???  I've shown 2x classes, I've indicated what I think the code should be like.. if I knew what the exact valid code is I would not be asking the question !

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call a static member with the `ClassName.memberName` syntax:

```
string localStr = First.theStringToGet;
```

If the member is not static, you must have an object created from this class and then use the `objectName.memberName` syntax:

```
// Assuming the that `theStringToGet` was not static.
First obj = new First();
string localStr = obj.theStringToGet;
```

You don't need Reflection for those things.

---

If the class name changes, this does not work with static members. If you need a static behaviour, you can use the singleton pattern and either derive the classes from the same base class, or let them implement the same interface. I will show the interface variant.

```
public interface IStringProvider
{
    string TheString { get; }
}

public class First : IStringProvider
{
    public static readonly First Instance = new First();

    private First() {} // Make constructor private, so no one else can instantiate.

    public string TheString => "some text";
}

public class Second : IStringProvider
{
    public static readonly First Instance = new Second();

    private Second() {}

    public string TheString => "another text";
}
```

Now, you can access the string like this

```
void AccessTheString(IStringProvider provider)
{
    string localStr = provider.TheString;
}
```

Example:

```
AccessTheString(First.Instance);
AccessTheString(Second.Instance);
```

Comment: The class name will change so I need to be able to use a variable to define the class, so in effect "localStr = [classRef].theStringToGet" - in fact this variable exists in multiple classes.